Different Python Versions in cmd and VS Code Terminals
A while ago, I had to switch to a different Python version in a rather complex way to use ROOT (for particle physics), which involved using pyenv and setting pyenv to the top of PATH in Windows 10.
However, I now want to use Python 3.11. For that, I put Python 3.11 folder above pyenv, both in user and global PATH.
When I run CMD using the search bar, I get Python 3.11. And when I use Jupyter in VS Code, I get it as well. However, when using VS Code Terminal, I get 3.8. There seems to be a 'contribution' to my terminal:
The following extensions have contributed to this terminal's environment:
Git: Enables the following features: git auth provider
Python: Activated environment for ~.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.8.10\python.exe
But I don't know what is happening. I have no knowledge programming, so I would appreciate if someone could explain what the problem exactly is and how to solve it.

You need to manually change the selected interpreter. Microsoft Python extension does not read from pyenv.

Do you mean searching for "select python interpreter" from the palette? I don't understand the second sentence. Does microsoft Python automatically force the terminal to use the version you select as the interpreter?
